# Is there any way to use an Angular Directive inside of React Virtual DOM

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I have the [following plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aWRhSplPjPcGLH9MjtVJ), and I am trying to add an angular directive to it. This may be impossible but I would like to do something like this...

```
  var Basic = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <p>
         <!-- This works <h1>test</h1> -->
         <jg-test></jg-test>
       </p>
      );
    }
  });
```

Where jgTest is the directive name. Is this possible? How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 3):

The only feasible way to do it would be [bootstrapping an angular app](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap), which has a template, which renders the directive.

The performance would likely be terrible, managing its lifecycle would be non trivial, and you'd have to wrap each directive in a component which does this.

Angular's not intended to be embedded like a component – it's an application framework, rather than a UI library like React.  This is why embedding React components in Angular directives works well, but not the reverse.